# How to setup wechat mini program push message service?

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I need to send service alerts to wechat mini app users.

I have been trying to setup it for wechat mini app but some how not able to get exact document to integrate service or I am missing something somewhere.I have been following this document link.
https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/framework/server-ability/message-push.html#option-url

But they are asking for Token which I do not know to get. 
Please someone help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/framework/open-ability/template-message.html

I tried above thing but it is not suitable for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In your question,there are following parts:

1. mini program user
2. your wechat mini program
3. wechat server
4. your own backend server

I suppose that you want to send messages to mini program user ,not receive messages from wechat server. The first link you give describes how to receive messages from wechat server. so it is not what you want.you provide the address and token to wechat server,and they can use the token to sign the request and you can verify the requsest if it is from wechat server.so the token you provide can be any valid string.you don't need to get it from somewhere

Second link is right ,and you can check this [link](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/api-backend/open-api/template-message/templateMessage.send.html) to get the rest api address and request parameters.you must use your https backend server to request wechat rest api.

Comment: It requires form_Id which is not on server. Why can't I sent message without form_Id ? I have ordering mini program which need to send notification message to wholesaler when any retailer place order.